# ARC custom delegate strange issue

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

OK, so here I have a strange problem I've been trying to figure out for the last couple of hours:

I have a simple storyboard app for iPad with two view controllers, `FirstViewController` which is the main view controller and a `ModalViewController` which appears on a Modal segue and it has a button called Done. 
I'm using ARC and the view controllers are specified to be for iPad.

I also have a custom delegate `UIModalViewControllerDelegate` which as you guess, is to dismiss the modal and pass data back to first view controller.

**UIModalViewControllerDelegate.h**

```
@protocol UIModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)btnDonePressed:(id)sender Values:(NSArray *)values;
@end
```

**FirstViewController.h**

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIModalViewControllerDelegate> {    
@private
    ModalViewController *mvc;
}
@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
// Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    mvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    mvc.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma UIModalViewControllerDelegate

-(void)btnDonePressed:(id)sender Values:(NSArray *)values {
        ...
}
```

**ModalViewController.h**

```
@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController {
    __weak id<UIModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<UIModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

**ModalViewController.m**

```
@implementation ModalViewController

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
}

-(void) buttonPressed:(id) sender {
    [delegate btnDonePressed:sender Values:values];
}
```

Now, couple of very interesting issues:

1- In the prepare for segue, after I set the `self.mvc.delegate = self;` the debugger shows that the delegate is still nil (!) However, when I use `NSLog(@"%@", self.mvc.delegate);` I get the address of the pointer which is not nil.

2- The code above does not work, because in `ModalViewController` the delegate is always nil. Therefore, `[delegate btnDonePressed:sender Values:values];` will never execute. I tried everything I knew might cause this issue, but nothing seem to work.

3- I guess that having a strong reference on delegate may resolve this issue but I don't want to violate the pattern and cause retain cycles issue. 
Does the private variable `ModalViewController *mvc;` in `FirstViewController` have issues with life cycle? When does a private variable get nilled? BTW, I also tried to replace it with `@property (strong, nonatomic) ModalViewController *mvc;` but nothing changed.

Comment: What happens if you change your delegate ivar to be declared like "__weak id <UIModalViewControllerDelegate>delegate;" and "@property (weak, nonatomic) id <UIModalViewControllerDelegate>delegate;"? I am a little rusty on how delegates work in iOS, but I believe you have to declare what type of delegate you are expecting when you create a property for one in your class.

Comment: I copied your code, and it worked for me (the only thing I added was a property in FirstViewController.h for mvc -- I assumed you had this since you use self.mvc).

Comment: @Paul, it's not necessary to add <UIModalViewControllerDelegate>, although I think it's good practice to do so.

Comment: @Paul Yes you are right. I originally had `id<UIModalViewControllerDelegate>delegate` but since I changed my code a lot in the past few hours, I just copied the wrong version here. However, that does not resolve the issue. (I updated the code above)

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, you are right. I actually prefer to use a private variable (I updated the code above). since I do not want to access it from ourside. 
It should not make any difference in terms of life cycle right? I mean private var vs. property

Comment: @rdelmar What version of Xcode are you using? This is very strange (!) The delegate is nil for me.

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter whether you use an ivar or a property, although the way you had it originally in your question wouldn't have compiled, since you referred to it using self.delegate. I'm using Xcode 4.5.2, but I don't think that should matter.

Answer (score 0):

> "I just copied the wrong version here. However, that does not resolve the issue. (I updated the code above)"

Since you mention copy-pasting. Make sure the original code has a `@synthesize` in there. This  problem looks like a mismatch in synthesized property vs. private variable names.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<UIModalViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
```

Your property as declared in combination with `@synthesize` will use the private variable named `delegate`. If you on accident leave out `@synthesize` a private variable with the name `_delegate` will be created automatically (note the underscore).

In your `buttonPressed:` method you access the private variable `delegate` directly. So that would potentially always return nil since the accessors actually use the underscored version.

Just to make sure, either remove the manually declared variable `delegate` or use `self.delegate` in your `buttonPressed:` method. See what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's thoughtful. I didn't leave out the @synthesize in the original code but it still does not work. What if I remove __weak id<UIModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate; ??? will it make any difference?

Comment: You can remove it anyway, it should be generated automatically. If it gives a compiler error after removing, it is indeed the problem described in my answer and you should start using `_delegate` in `buttonPressed:`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers. I finally found the solution to this problem.

Actually, the code is perfectly correct. The problem is the `UINavigationController`, in which the Modal View Controller is embedded.

Instead of

```
myModalWindowViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
myModalWindowViewController.delegate = self;
```

I do

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];
myModalWindowViewController = (MyModalWindowViewController *)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
myModalWindowViewController.delegate = self;
```

I didn't know that when you segue to a ViewController which is embedded in a NavigationController, the DestinationViewController is the NavigationController and NOT the ViewController. My bad!